# Can I control the height of wrapped lines?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an HTML document. In CSS there is the line-height property. This controls the spacing *between* lines.

In addition, I want to control the spacing *within* lines that wrap.

For example, I might want the spacing between lines to be 1.5em, but when a line wraps, I might want the spacing within the wrapped line to be 1.1em. Is this possible? If so, what CSS element lets me control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong. [Line height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) defines height of single line (letter glyph may be smaller).

To achieve effect that you want, you can add padding of `.4em` to wrapper:

```css
div {
  padding: .5em 0;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text
</div>
<div>Single line of text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you rethink how you use the line-height property. Line-height is specifically good for achieving the spacing when something wraps. So what i would do (if i understand you correctly)

Give the Element where the text is inside:

```
margin: 1.5em 0;
line-height: 1.1em;
```

so you use the margin to define the spacing between seperate lines and the line-height to define the spacing when wrapped